# Texturing a sphere in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Is it possible to texture a sphere part by part? For example we can use 6 textures on 6 sides of the cube making it possible for us to texture the cube face by face. Is it possible to do the same in sphere??  I do not want to overlap one texture on the other, but use different textures on different parts of the sphere. For example first 1/4th of sphere with texture 1, second 1/4th of sphere with texture 2...so on. Can we achieve this using THREE.js or any other library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SphereGeometry` constructor has parameters that let you construct a sector of a sphere:

```
THREE.SphereGeometry( radius, widthSegments, heightSegments, phiStart, phiLength, thetaStart, thetaLength )
```

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to use the following pattern:

```
var parent = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add( parent );

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 24, 16, 0 * Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2 );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture0 } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
parent.add( mesh );

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 24, 16, 1 * Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2 );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture1 } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
parent.add( mesh );

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 24, 16, 2 * Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2 );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture2 } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
parent.add( mesh );

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 24, 16, 3 * Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2 );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture3 } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
parent.add( mesh );
```

three.js r.63

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working great. There is a problem, suppose i have 32 tiles/image to be filled, i would require 32 spheres, when i do it my browser crashes very often and in IE it doesn't even show up a single tile. My main intention is load my page faster by bringing in images part by part rather than loading whole image at once. Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: The question was about 4 tiles, not 32. Consider [other approaches](http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable.html), and post a new, detailed queestion if you are having problems.

Comment: Hey i need a favor, would you please suggest me some articles to go through to understand the factors or constraints that should be kept in mind while developing a high performance webgl application. I need to understand the factors that affect the webgl performance.

Comment: That is a very general webgl question. If you have more questions, you will have to make a new post and tag it as webgl.

Comment: I have made a new post regarding the issue. Please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20606350/canvas-renderer-crashes-when-using-multiple-geometry-in-three-js