# Canvas renderer crashes when using multiple geometry in three.js

Tags: three.js

Based on certain parameters am creating multiple sphere geometries by specifying different PI and theta values. For example

```
var parent = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add( parent );

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 24, 16, 0 * Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2 );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture0 } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
parent.add( mesh );

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 24, 16, 1 * Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2 );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture1 } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
parent.add( mesh );

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 24, 16, 2 * Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2 );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture2 } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
parent.add( mesh );

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 24, 16, 3 * Math.PI/2, Math.PI/2 );
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: texture3 } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
parent.add( mesh );
```

When i create more than one geometry, it works fine with THREE.WebGLRenderer but when i use THREE.CanvasRenderer() the browser crashes. How to fix the issue. I want my application to run on IE10 and below which only supports THREE.CanvasRenderer.

Thanks in advance.