# Creating multiple segments of a sphere in three.js

Tags: three.js

I want to create a series of segments of sphere which later can be combined to give a illusion of entire sphere. I want to do this so that i can use different textures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below link

[Texturing a sphere in THREE.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420220/texturing-a-sphere-in-three-js)

In addition to the above answer, you can accomplish this dynamically as well using different combination of the PI and theta values, so that you can decide on number of sphere to be created at run time ,based on the number of your textures.

Comment: thank "WestLangley" for answering that question. I just showed you the link.